# Buddy Systemin Memory Allocation

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Consider the following memory sequence for a certain process :

```
Request 100K (A)
Request 240K (B)
Request 64K (C) 
Request 256K (D)
Release B
Release A
Request 75K (E)
Release C
Release E
Release D
```

I am trying to understand how can I draw a binary tree representation for a buddy allocator, but I am not sure if I understand it correctly or not. So if I need to draw the tree immediately after the release of B, this will be my solution :

[image]

So is this a correct binary tree representing this example immediately after releasing B or did I miss something?